# val() loop possibilities opposed to each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

So a bit of a hypothetical question (and don't hesitate to let me know if there is another post with the same question - I didn't find one though)

So, the .val() method returns the current value of the first element matched by the selector. Is there another "shorthand" jquery method that get's the value of all matched elements and returns an array?

Or am I safest just doing this:

```
var myResult = [];
$(".myClass").each(function(){
    myResult.push($(this).val());
});
```

As I said above, I looked for something, but it might just be that I have to use .each()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's no shorthand. However, there is a shorter method than yours:

```
var myResult = $(".myClass").map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

and if you really wanted to, you could create your own shorthand:

```
$.fn.getValAsArray = function(){
    return this.map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
};

var myResult = $(".myClass").getValAsArray();
```

a few more alternatives:

`$.map`

```
var myResult = $.map($.makeArray($(".myClass")),function(input){
    return input.value;
});
// or
var myResult = $.map($(".myClass").get(),function(input){
    return input.value;
});
```

`[].map`

```
var myResult = $.makeArray($(".myClass")).map(function(input){
    return input.value;
});
// or
var myResult = $(".myClass").get().map(function(input){
    return input.value;
});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, this is possible in normal JavaScript when working on an array too (without the excess `.get` and with a parameter.

Comment: I'd call it `vals()` but okay :)

Comment: Tops brother. And you @LightnessRacesinOrbit, didn't see that previous question - apologies.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Evil! Filter's function argument is not intended to have side-effects, but to return a boolean for filtration.

Comment: @SheikhHeera While it obviously works, you're just misusing `filter`...and isn't relevant to this answer. If you want to do it like that, you should use `each`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera you could also use .html(), but just like .filter(), it's not the right tool for the job. http://jsfiddle.net/RDvRW/4/

Comment: Got it and thanks, I was just curious what if I want to do it in another way, but your answer is perfect, anyways.

Comment: @KevinB I'll do you one worse: http://jsfiddle.net/CTypq/

Comment: @Ian, but the idea is appreciable as an alternative and I didn't even imagine it until now. :)

Comment: @Ian If you used event delegation, it could be used as a way of re-populating the array on demand when new elements are added, after emptying the array of course. :p

Comment: This is a really great answer now with all these alternatives, really a nice one! Thx

Comment: @KevinB I'm intrigued and confused; can you show an example? :)

Comment: @Ian http://jsfiddle.net/CTypq/1/

Comment: @KevinB Ahh I see...I thought you meant some "automatic" way of detecting (no triggering). How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/Teb4q/ ! The `remove` event is only there because of jQuery UI. Unfortunately, no support for newly added elements. (I know there's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I've been looking way too much into this kind of stuff since we started making these pointless examples, and now I'm interested in tapping into better support for detecting when an element is removed (and added) with or without jQuery.